# Dynamically bind data in HighChart Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, highcharts

I'm trying to load data in to highcharts by passing the data from backend using Flask/Python. How can I do it better rather than passing each value like the way I'm doing now. It makes changing the code very hard. I tried to use for-in loop but that didn't work, Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
var barChartData = [
                        {% for item in bar_values %}
                            "{{item|safe}}",
                        {% endfor %}
                       ];

var barChartLabels = [
                        {% for item in bar_labels %}
                                "{{item|safe}}",
                        {% endfor %}
                    ];


    Highcharts.chart('statInfo', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Statistical Class'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'No. of People'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Count: <b>{point.y:.1f} </b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: [
            [barChartLabels[0], parseInt(barChartData[0])],
            [barChartLabels[1], parseInt(barChartData[1])],
            [barChartLabels[2], parseInt(barChartData[2])],
            [barChartLabels[3], parseInt(barChartData[3])],
            [barChartLabels[4], parseInt(barChartData[4])],
            [barChartLabels[5], parseInt(barChartData[5])],
            [barChartLabels[6], parseInt(barChartData[6])],
            [barChartLabels[7], parseInt(barChartData[7])],
            [barChartLabels[8], parseInt(barChartData[8])],
            [barChartLabels[9], parseInt(barChartData[9])]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }] });
```

Comment: They way I have set up my Flask/highchart is that I have a function in python, that returns a highchart JSON object. In JS I use ajax, to receive this JSON object and graph it. Something similar to this: https://www.fontenay-ronan.fr/dynamic-charts-with-highcharts-sqlite-and-python/

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ewolden. That's the approach I decided to take on as well. The variable needs to be pre-processed for highcharts to work I believe.

Comment: Yeah, it does need some pre-processing. But setting it up this way, while it is a bit more work initially, will make it a lot easier to change and maintain later on.